# Close loop circuit vs an open one in regards to an electrical bicycle light system

Tags: ac, dc

From what I know about DC current, for it to flow you need 2 points with different voltage (while AC doesn't flow from point to point), this why DC batteries discharge overtime, when not used, because they are surrounded with a 0V environment.

I am building a light system for my electrical bicycle and have 2 options. I can use my 12V source as a close loop or I can just connect my light system (one end) to my bicycle metal frame and use the bicycle as 0V. My questions is what will be the difference?

Comment: Your opening paragraph is wrong and irrelevant to the question it seems?

Comment: I agree with andy, the answer is: anything, you will just need one less wire.

Comment: Andy, could you elaborate why is my first paragraph is wrong?

Comment: Battteries self-discharge over time due to internal chemical reactions, not "because they are surrounded with a 0 volt environment".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it would not work unless you attached the negative of you battery to you bicycle frame as well in which case you could avoid the need of an extra wire. Though, since electricity flows through the least resistant path and I'd have to guess that a proper copper wire would have less resistance than a bike frame (you should not trust me on this one, just use a multimeter and check this one out yourself), I'd probably avoid using the frame as a wire but if you want to place your battery quite far away from your "light system" connecting your batteries negative terminal to the frame might save you some wire and could make your project look a tad bit better without the wire hanging around.

Comment: So if I don't connect my negative battery end to the frame it will become 12V and there will be no flow. Thanks.

Comment: *"since electricity flows through the least resistant path"*  - NO, it flows through *all* available paths, with the current in each path depending on the resistances (assuming a fixed voltage).

Answer (score 1):

Your lighting circuit must have a complete path from the positive terminal of the battery, through the lights, and back to the negative terminal of the battery.  The "return" path may through a wire, or through the bicycle frame.  Either way will work, but it may be easier to ensure a reliable low resistance path if you use a wire.